# repeat animation from the new object position

Tags: objective-c, animation

I would like to simply animate an UIImageView to move infinitely without timer or displaylink. So, here is what I've done:

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{self.vitesseY = self.vc + self.vitesseY;
                         self.balle.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.balle.imageView.center.x+self.vitesseX, self.balle.imageView.center.y+self.vitesseY);}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){NSLog(@"fini");}];
```

The issue is that my imageView go back to the initial position but I would like to repeat the animation from the new position. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you're doing here, is to use a timer.

But if you really want to do it this way for some weird reason, you need to add a new animate call when the completion block is called (but this is unnecessarily convoluted and potentially bad for performance). The reason is that UIView will evaluate your animations block once, and then repeat that same animation over and over.

Comment: thank you, I have already try to call again the animation on completion block, but as you said, bad for performance... So, I will finally do it with a timer or CADisplayLink.